# Android tests throws exception in Application class

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

I have simple Application class:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {
    public MainApplication() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

and simple test:

```
public class SimpleTests extends AndroidTestCase {
    public void testSum() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

why I get an Exception on my tests starting? How my test is related with the Application class?

```
Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.Exception'
Empty test suite.
```

Android Studio v.1.5.1

**UPDATE**: my Application subclass of course is more complex and contains business logic in method "onCreate". I do not want to run this logic when I run my tests.

Comment: "why I get an Exception on my tests starting?" -- assuming that you have this `Application` subclass registered in your manifest (`android:name` on the `<application>` element), an instance of that `Application` subclass will be created every time your app's process starts. "How my test is related with the Application class?" -- apparently, you are testing an Android app that is using this `Application` class as described in my previous paragraph. If you feel that this is not the case, perhaps you might post the relevant manifest and test code.

Comment: Thanks. How I prevent running an Application subclass only in my tests? And see update, please.

Comment: "How I prevent running an Application subclass only in my tests?" -- you don't. You fix your `Application` subclass so that it will work when being tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is override Application class for tests.

1. Use custom testInstrumentationRunner in gradle configuration:

   ```
   testInstrumentationRunner 'com.xxx.test.CustomTestRunner'
   ```
2. Implement Runner that doesn't use your Application class:

   ```
   public class CustomTestRunner extends InstrumentationTestRunner {
       @Override
       public Application newApplication(ClassLoader cl, String className, Context context) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
           return super.newApplication(cl, Application.class.getName(), context);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are throwing it by code in constructer of Application

Remove

```
throw new Exception();
```

From MainApplication constructer